# Trying to give color to column field headers in pivot table with vba

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to give white color to the font titles of the columns in my pivot table.

[image]

I tried doing it like this:

```
' Format column field headers
For Each pvtField In pvtTable.ColumnFields
    With pvtField.LabelRange
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 77) ' Dark Blue
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' White
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
Next pvtField
```

But it didnt work, then I tried a more manual way, like this:

```
' Column headers are the fith row in TableRange2
Set headerRow = pvtTable.TableRange2.Rows(5)
With headerRow
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 77) ' Dark Blue
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' White
    '.Font.ColorIndex = 2 ' White ' White
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
```

With this second code I manged to get the .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 77) ' Dark Blue correct, but not the font color white.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using `TableRange2.Rows(5)` to locate the the header is not reliable. It depends on how many page fields on pvt table.
- `TableRange1` represents the range containing the entire PivotTable range, but doesn't include page fields.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [PivotTable.TableRange1 property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.tablerange1?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm235098)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.Union method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Sub HighLightPvtHeader()
    Dim pvtTable As PivotTable, pvtField As PivotField
    Dim headerRow As Range
    Set pvtTable = Sheet1.PivotTables(1)
    With pvtTable.TableRange1.Rows(2)
        Set headerRow = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1) ' modify as needed
    End With
    For Each pvtField In pvtTable.ColumnFields
        Set headerRow = Union(headerRow, pvtField.LabelRange)
    Next pvtField
    With headerRow
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 77) ' Dark Blue
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]